# Set changepassword="true" in apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I have collected all users in a certain OU. Now i would like to change a parameter in the objects. But i get an error code `TypeError: Cannot find function changePasswordAtNextLogin in object`

```
function admsdk() {

    var x = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
        customer: "my_customer",
        query: "orgUnitPath='/LegacyMail'", 
    });
    Logger.log(x);

    for(var i in x) {
        x[i].changePasswordAtNextLogin(true);
    }
}
```

The object have the parameter "`changePasswordAtNextLogin`" but i get errors any way:

[14-02-21 12:13:41:182 CET] {users=[{etag="7XeU3X9xgwyeKXCCsYZGUBcBlgw/8gkNyn34hZeT3Dwd78gpIG0OyMEo", orgUnitPath=/LegacyMail, emails=[{address=abbec@mydomain.com, primary=true}, suspended=false, primaryEmail=abbec@mydomain.com, kind=admin#directory#user, id=1033d75074613787551986, isMailboxSetup=true, **changePasswordAtNextLogin=false**, customerId=wC030c3310,

Now it look's like this, but i can't get it to work:

```
 function admsdk() {

  var x = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
    customer: "my_customer",
    query: "orgUnitPath='/LegacyMail'", 
  });
  Logger.log(x);

  for(var i in x){
   x[i].changePasswordAtNextLogin = true;
      AdminDirectory.Users.update(changePasswordAtNextLogin, x);
  }
}
```

It fail's on the AdminDirectory.Users.update(changePasswordAtNextLogin, x); am i thinking right resourceKey = the user variable, and the resource the property ?
  AdminDirectory.Users.update(resource, userKey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and in that way?

```
function admsdk() {

  var userlist = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
                 customer: "my_customer",
                 query: "orgUnitPath='/LegacyMail'", 
                 });

  var users=userList.users;

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      users[i].changePasswordAtNextLogin = true;
      AdminDirectory.Users.update(users[i], users[i].primaryEmail);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

changePasswordAtNextLogin is a property not a function.

Try -

```
x[i].changePasswordAtNextLogin = true
```

Make sure to also do an update at the end

```
  AdminDirectory.Users.update(resource, userKey)
```

Comment: Hi Arun, and thank you for the help, the first thing helped a lot, but the update isn't working for me, the userKey is the user but the resource should it be the property? It looks like this now:

function admsdk() {
  
  var x = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
    customer: "my_customer",
    query: "orgUnitPath='/LegacyMail'", 
  });
  Logger.log(x);
   
  for(var i in x){
   x[i].changePasswordAtNextLogin = true;
      AdminDirectory.Users.update(changePasswordAtNextLogin, x);
  }
}